# how to update database records using form

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, forms, textbox

There are number of records which I gather them from mysql say thease:

```
id      name     mark 
1234    john     18
53      smith    12
324     mike     15
...
```

I want to build a form to give ability to edit(update) all `mark`s at once
I know that I can show them at the form using textbox value property.
But how can I Identify the exact same record when I want to process the posted form, in order to update the correct filed? and surly, I don't know how many records are there in the form.

The idea might be identifying the records through the `id` field.
but how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this application is for administrative use only:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="_ID_VALUE_" />
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="_NAME_VALUE_" />
<input type="text" name="mark" id="mark" value="_MARK_VALUE_" />
```

then

```
UPDATE table SET mark = '_SANITIZED_MARK_VALUE_' WHERE id = "_SANITIZED_ID_VALUE_";
```

If it's an application for the end user, you don't want to trust that he/she won't change the value of the hidden input. In this case, you'll most likely want to store the `id`, `name`, and `mark` in a `$_SESSION` variable and do comparisons on the `post` to figure out which record pertains to which `id`, and then build your `update` statement accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

When you build your form, use the ID from the database as part of each text field's NAME attribute. Then when you receive your array of posted values, you can process the keys to find out the ID of the record you should be updating. For example, you could have your fields named "record-1234", "record-53", etc. Then you would iterate over the keys in $_POST, split them on "-" and use the resulting IDs in your UPDATE query.

Comment: thanks that should work, but user can change the ID in the from and send them causing problems.

Comment: @john That's true. I saw you said that you wanted to update all the marks at once, so I assumed this was an administrative interface for a trusted user. If you want to restrict people to only updating certain records, then you need some kind of validation like wanovak mentioned.

Comment: @blake I like for field names to be descriptive. It might be old-fashioned of me. Another reason is that when PHP receives all-numeric field names, it will probably end up treating them as numeric indices to $_POST, even though $_POST is supposed to be an associative array. I'm not aware of any serious problems that might cause, but I was being paranoid.